# How to customize RESTful Routes in Rails (basics)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, routes, nested-routes

I have read through the Rails docs for [Routing](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Routing.html), [Restful Resources](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Resources.html), and the [UrlHelper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html), and still don't understand best practices for creating complex/nested routes.  The example I'm working on now is for events, which has_many rsvps.  So a user's looking through a list of events, and clicks register, and goes through a registration process, etc.  I want the urls to look like this:

```
/events
/events/123 # possible without title, like SO
/events/123/my-event-title # canonical version
/events/my-category/123/my-event-title # also possible like this
/events/123/my-event-title/registration/new
... and all the restful nested resouces.
```

Question is, how do I accomplish this with the minimal amount of code?

Here's what I currently have:

```
map.resources :events do |event|
  event.resources :rsvps, :as => "registration"
end
```

That gets me this:

```
/events/123/registration
```

What's the best way to accomplish the other 2 routes?

```
/events/123/my-event-title # canonical version
/events/my-category/123/my-event-title # also possible like this
```

Where `my-category` is just an array of 10 possible types the event can be.

I've modified `Event#to_param` to return `"#{self.id.to_s}-#{self.title.parameterize}"`, but I'd prefer to have `/id/title` with the whole canonical-ness

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the SEO-friendly URLs you describe do not conform to the way Rails generates RESTful routes, you will need to use regular routes to set these up. For example:

```
map.show_event 'events/:id/:event_title', :controller => 'events', :action => 'show'
```

Don't feel that you have to use the automatically generated RESTful routes for absolutely everything in your application. It's not always a good fit for what you're trying to do. Even the Rails routing guide says so:

> While RESTful routing has become the
>   Rails standard, there are still plenty
>   of places where the simpler regular
>   routing works fine. You can even mix
>   the two styles within a single
>   application. In general, you should
>   prefer RESTful routing when possible,
>   because it will make parts of your
>   application easier to write. But
>   there’s no need to try to shoehorn
>   every last piece of your application
>   into a RESTful framework if that’s not
>   a good fit.

Comment: okay cool, that's basically all I was wondering, "is it okay to not use map.resources?".  Thanks for confirming that.  I'll do what you described :).

Answer (score -1):

Have you looked at the Rails [routing guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)?  It's got lots of info to get you understanding the router and includes a section on [nested resources](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources).